# Using Ngrok to connect to local PostgreSQL from AWS Lamba

Tags: lambda, ngrok, node-postgres

I'm trying to use [node-postgres (PG)](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) to connect to my localhost PostgreSQL database running on port 5432.  To do this, I've setup [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel my request.

```
./ngrok tcp 5432
```

The code below works when running locally (even when tunneling using ngrok).  It also works on lambda when I connect to an external database - in my case hosted by Heroku.

```
'use strict';

const PG = require('pg');

// These credentials work locally
var credentials = {
    user: 'MyUsername',
    host: 'tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io',
    database: 'MyDatabase',
    password: 'MyPassword',
    port: '12829',
    ssl: true
};

const pool = new PG.Pool(credentials);

const connectionPromise = function(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            err ? reject(err) : resolve({
                client: client,
                done: done
            })
        })
    });
};


exports.handler = Handler;

function Handler(event, context, callback) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    console.log("Calling handler in Lambda");
    return connectionPromise().then(function (conn) {
        console.log("Success");
        callback(null);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Error");
        callback(err);
    });
};

// Uncomment this code to run locally.
// Handler(null, {}, function(){
//     console.log("Exiting");
//     process.exit();
// });
```

However, when I attempt to use node-postgres + Ngrok to connect to my localhost database via Lambda ...

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:12829

Full Error Message

> START RequestId: 3ac634ef-310e-41ab-b20f-14c86271b5d7 Version: $LATEST
>   2019-01-21T16:14:27.020Z  3ac634ef-310e-41ab-b20f-14c86271b5d7    Calling
>   handler in Lambda
>   2019-01-21T16:14:27.117Z  3ac634ef-310e-41ab-b20f-14c86271b5d7    { Error:
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:12829
>       at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)   code: 'ENOTFOUND',   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>   hostname: 'tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io',   host: 'tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io',
>   port: 12829 }
>   2019-01-21T16:14:27.118Z  3ac634ef-310e-41ab-b20f-14c86271b5d7    Error
>   2019-01-21T16:14:27.155Z  3ac634ef-310e-41ab-b20f-14c86271b5d7    {"errorMessage":"getaddrinfo
>   ENOTFOUND tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io
>   tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:12829","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["errnoException
>   (dns.js:50:10)","GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete]
>   (dns.js:92:26)"]} END RequestId: 3ac634ef-310e-41ab-b20f-14c86271b5d7
>   REPORT RequestId: 3ac634ef-310e-41ab-b20f-14c86271b5d7    Duration:
>   136.26 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 23 MB

Is lambda blocking ngrok?

Answer (score 5):

Remove **`tcp://`** from ngrok hostname:

```
var credentials = {
    user: 'MyUsername',
    host: '0.tcp.ngrok.io',
    database: 'MyDatabase',
    password: 'MyPassword',
    port: '12829',
    ssl: true
};
```